# Soft linking an executable in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, executable, symlink, julia

I am trying to use Julia with Cygwin (neither of which I know very much about, clearly). I have built and tested Julia and all seems fine. To run Julia from the terminal, it seems like I need to be in Julia/usr/bin and then type ./julia.exe (or just./julia). This doesn't work in any other directory.

The Julia documentation says

'Once it is built, you can run the julia executable using its full path in the directory created above (the julia directory), or, to run it from anywhere... add a soft link to the julia executable in the julia directory to /usr/local/bin (or any suitable directory already in your path)'

and since I want to be able to use Julia in whatever directory, this seems like a good idea. However, I have tried various permutations of

ln -s /Julia/usr/bin/julia /bin

(using /bin and not /usr/local/bin because that seems to be where things are kept in cygwin as opposed to linux proper), and every time I've typed julia or ./julia I just get a message saying -bash: julia: command not found.

I expect this is really very easy - I'm not very experienced. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - this problem has been resolved. I tried many different possible things for the correct path that julia.exe was under, including the relative path Coding/Julia/usr/bin, (I should have mentioned that in the first place) which lead to the answer I accepted below. Using that answer, I can now run Julia anywhere in any directory with the command julia.

Comment: I use /usr/local/bin in Cygwin all the time for anything that doesn't install via the Cygwin setup program.  Have you tried `ln -s /Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe /usr/local/bin/julia` (or wherever you want to put it)?  That is, include the `.exe` part on the command line?

Comment: Just gave it a try (in /usr/local/bin in case it does make a difference) - still getting the same error message. I've tried with .exe and without, and and prefacing with ./ (not completely sure what that does except it makes .exes go) and I haven't been able to get it work.

Comment: You could check the PATH and permissions of your */bin directories.  If you do `echo $PATH`, you should get `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:` as the first entries.   What's the output of `ls -l /Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe`, `ls -l /usr/local/bin/julia` after you tried the `ln -s` command?

Comment: Here are all the relevant commands - seems like it should be working? but still the same error message.

Ben@Ben-PC ~
$ ln -s Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe /usr/local/bin/julia

Ben@Ben-PC ~
$ julia
-bash: julia: command not found

Ben@Ben-PC ~
$ ls -l Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Ben None 1515029 Jan 13 22:16 Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe

Ben@Ben-PC ~
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/julia
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Ben None 30 Jan 17 21:21 /usr/local/bin/julia -> Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe

Comment: Here is what I get from echo $PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0

Comment: It looks like your Julia executable is in a path below your home directory, is that correct?  Or at least the path you use is not the _full_ path, since it's not prefaced with `/`.  You need to use the full path.  If it's in your home directory, it'll be something like `/home/Ben/Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe/` if you plan on keeping it there.  I normally run `make install` and packages generally default to installing to /usr/local, and then you wouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: Ah, it works now, using the full directory. Thanks very much! Do you believe in bitcoin tips?

Comment: No thanks, but you can mark my answer as right :)

Comment: Please update your question to include the information from the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `ln` needs to link to an *absolute* path, not a relative one.  The problem was not apparent in the OP, because the path you wrote *looked* absolute because it started with `/`.

Something like `ln -s /home/<username>/Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe /usr/local/bin/julia.exe` should work.

Note:
By including `.exe` on the end of your LINK_NAME you get the ability to call both `julia` and `julia.exe`. Whether you intend to use the long form or not, it's best to include `.exe` on both the TARGET and LINK_NAME.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm willing to be wrong, but doesn't starting a path without a `/` always look for that path below (i.e., relative) to the current directory?  The _actual_ path being used was `Coding/Julia/usr/bin/julia.exe`, that's the relative path I'm referring to.

Comment: Yes, a path that doesn't start with `/` is a relative path, and is interpreted relative to the current directory. A path starting with `/` is by definition an absolute path, and is interpreted relative to the root directory. The path in the question is `/Julia/usr/bin/julia`. That's an absolute path, but it's invalid because there's (presumably) no `/Julia` directory. I'm referring to the path in the question; I didn't read the comments.

Comment: If you look in the comments, the OP actually uses a relative path, and I noted that discrepancy in my answer.

Comment: You should include the `.exe` in both arguments. I modified the answer to indicate why.